# Copy files from one bucket/folder to another through GWT java application on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, file-io, google-cloud-storage

Need to copy files/documents from one GCS Bucket/folder into another Bucket/Folder via AppEngine GWT Java application.

Use case: On accepting a document on the screen, the document is duplicated into another location via this application.

Comment: On SO you must ask specific programming questions and not asking to be provided with a total solution.

Comment: Yes exactly, need to know how can this be achieved. Don't want the user to download the document and upload again on the application. Could be done using gsutils and I have done that but that shall be manual. Please help If this is possible?

Comment: Which API are you using to access GCS? You can issue a copy-in-the-cloud operation.

Comment: I am using the Blobstore Java API to access GCS. Please give me some link/detail about copy-in-the-cloud operation